# Highcharts show percentage in the center of the solid gauge chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am very new to Highcharts. I am trying to use the solid gauge. The problem is that the percentage text is not present in the center. Is there anyway to put the percentage in the center of the chart?

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge'
            },

            title: {
                text: ''
            },

            tooltip: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '16px'
                },
                pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
                positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
                    return {
                        x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
                        y: 180
                    };
                }
            },

            pane: {
                center: ['50%', '27%'],
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 360,
                background: [{ // Track for Stand
                    outerRadius: '62%',
                    innerRadius: '38%',
                    backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                    borderWidth: 0,

                }],

            },

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                lineWidth: 0,
                tickPositions: []
            },

            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    borderWidth: '34px',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    linecap: 'round',
                    stickyTracking: false
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Stand',
                borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                data: [{
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                    radius: '50%',
                    innerRadius: '50%',
                    y: 50
                }]
            }]
        },
});
```

The x and y in the label option can set the position but I want it to be dynamic.
Secondly I want it to be always shown. Here is the result of the code above.

[image: Chart]

Comment: The answer to this question might help you: [How can I style my highcharts solid gauge to have a background behind the percentage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110398/how-can-i-style-my-highcharts-solid-gauge-to-have-a-background-behind-the-percen)

Comment: Somethign similar : https://jsfiddle.net/b5cakdbm/

Comment: Thanks for help It really solved the problem